# Is it possible use composite triggers in conjunction with micro-batching with dataflow?

Tags: apache-beam, dataflow

We have an unbounded `PCollection` `PCollection<TableRow> source` that we are inserting to BigQuery.

An easy "by the book" way to fire windows every 500 thousand messages or five minutes would be:

```java
source.apply("GlobalWindow", Window.<TableRow>into(new GlobalWindows())
    .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterFirst.of(
         AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(500000),
         AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(5))))
     ).withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardMinutes(1440)).discardingFiredPanes())
```

You would think that applying the following to the fired window/pane would allow you to write contents of the fired pane to BigQuery:

```java
.apply("BatchWriteToBigQuery", BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
.to(destination)
.withMethod(BigQueryIO.Write.Method.FILE_LOADS)
.withNumFileShards(NUM_FILE_SHARDS)
.withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
.withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND));
```

But this would yield a compile error `An exception occured while executing the Java class. When writing an unbounded PCollection via FILE_LOADS, triggering frequency must be specified`

Relatively easy fix would be to add `.withTriggeringFrequency(Duration.standardMinutes(5))` to the above, which would essentially render the idea of inserting *either* every five minutes or every *N* messages completely void, and you might as well get rid of the windowing in that case anyway.

Is there a way to actually accomplish this?

Answer (score -1):

`FILE_LOADS` requires triggering frequency.

If you want more realtime results then you can use `STREAMING_INSERTS`

Reference https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.19.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.Write.Method.html#FILE_LOADS

Comment: So is your answer is, no, it is not possible to trigger `FILE_LOADS` either every N elements OR every N minutes? Because I kind of have your answer included in my question already.

Comment: The answer is  NO for `FILE_LOAD`. However, my intent for the answer was to provide an alternative which is `STREAMING_INSERT` as it was not covered in the question.

Comment: @ChristianW. -As Ankur mentioned there are two independent things happening in your code. 1. There is logic to emit panes at a certain frequency based on your Trigger logic and 2. There is a separate logic to write those emitted rows to Bigquery. If you want to have the triggering logic control writes to Bigquery then STREAMING_INSERT needs to be used. If you want to have an independent logic to write at a certain frequency which has no bearing on how the Pane was generated then FILE_LOADS method will do the trick for you.